# Water tank logic using only C arithmetic operators?

Tags: c

This is an assignment and we are not allowed to use any logical/relational/conditional/bitwise operators/loops/if/else statements. The problem states that there are three holes in a tank and water exits from each. Take in value for total water in the tank, if the water in the tank is `200` gal or more, water exits at `1.5` gal per minute from the 3rd hole, `1.3` gal/min from 2nd, and `1.1` from 1st hole. If the water level is below 200 gals, water only exits from the bottom two holes. If the water level is below 150 gallons, water only comes out of the bottom hole. What is the total water exiting per minute? We have to figure this out only using `%`, `/`, `*`, `+`, `-`,`=` operators. I tried the following,

```
    #define HoleOneRange 200
    #define HoleTwoRange 150
    #define HoleThreeRange 100
    int WaterLevel,totalExiting;
    totalExiting = ( (WaterLevel/HoleOneRange) * (HoleOneRange - WaterLevel * 1.5) )
```

But I also need an expression for hole 1 and 2 which I can't figure out for the last one hour and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: These sorts of questions are of very limited benefit to anyone. Which functions are you allowed to call?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand that and I apologize for that in advance, we are not allowed to call any builtin functions or create our own.

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC I have added in the original question what I tried.

Comment: One advantage of being ancient is that you don't have to deal with such nonsense.  It's like asking a football player to perform with the laces on their boots tied together. You can perform. It is miraculous what you can do. It isn't sensible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wish me and the 150 some students in my class could tell this to our CS professor, he tests our math more than our programming skills which makes zero sense.

Comment: It may be a reflection on his (lack of) coding skills. The code will be contorted and hard to maintain. Were it submitted for code review, it would be rejected.  However, my bitching about what's out of your control doesn't help much. 'Tis bedtime here. I'm going to use that as an excuse to do nothing for 8+ hours.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this would literally take 2 minutes if conditional statements and other operators were allowed, and the program would be stable also. Anyways, thanks for looking.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260444/print-one-if-two-numbers-are-equal) is posed by someone suffering from the same sadistic teacher that you have.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wouldn't be surprised, the same teacher has teaches two sections of 150 students each, everyone I spoke to was confused about the logic to go by for this problem.

Comment: This seams like the only valid occasion to use goto. :-)

Comment: @schorsch312 is the input known to be an integral value?

Comment: The unreasonable constraints make this question of negative use to future users/visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is not **at all** in the spirit of SO as mentioned in the comments, these kind of questions are very common because of course curriculums.

Your whole problem reduces to comparing whether a quantity is greater than or less than another quantity.

Say the water quantity is `x`.

You want to know whether `x >= 200`, you start with

```
int y = x / 200;
```

Now `y` will be `0` if `x < 200` and a positive number other wise.

But ideally we would like it to be `{0, 1}` so that we can simply multiply with rate and get the total rate.

So we do this -

```
float z = (float)y;
z = z / (z + 1);
```

Now if `y` was 0, z will also be zero. If it was one or more it will be some quantity just less than one.

Now you can do

```
float rate1 = RATE_FOR_HOLE * (int) (z * 2); // This is 1.1 if I understand correctly.
```

Similarly you can calculate for second hole. For the third hole it will always be 1.5. Add up and return.

**Edit**: There is small issue about `z` becoming `0.4999` instead of `0.5` in case y is `1`. To get rid of this special case, simply multiply `y` by `2` and the case of `1` will be eliminated.

Demo: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/mGVUjM)

Comment: I think the integer division for setting 0 or 1 based on range that is mentioned here is a key part of the solution.  The linked question also has useful input — an equality test.